# TwinCAT 3.0 NCI Master/Slave

Tags: master-slave, twincat, coupling

I am trying to master/slave in TwinCAT 3.0 by coupling.

[image]

It is working when I move them in PTP (MC_MoveAbs or MC_Jog). But when I run NCI, I keep getting this error  "3/24/2022 4:29:20 PM 366 ms | 'TCNC' (500): NC-Ctrl (R0), Cannot configurate axis 1 into group 1 because a slave is coupled or this axis is a slave itself (CoupleState: 1) !

[image]

Do you guys have any idea to solve this problem while using NCI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error description says - it's impossible to configurate an axis into NCI group, if a slave is coupled to said axis.
Solution is to configurate axis into the NCI group when it's decoupled and couple afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I mastered after NCI grouping and it worked.